# router.get inside router.post, can't reach router.get

Tags: node.js, rest

am trying to have a router.get inside router.post, I need to compare the information provided by the user to the one in the database and then post it if it does not exists. The problem is the router.get is never reached. No errors, and postman keeps "sending request" with no end. Is it possible to have a router.get inside router.post?, if yes how?, If no, how do I get info from router.get to pass to router.post? I need to run the api from ..../new, and do all the work from there. Thanks in advance

```js
//register
router.post('/new', (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log("jumped out");
    var user_id, password0, password1; 
    user_id = req.body.user_id;
    password0 = req.body.password0;
    password1 = req.body.password1;

    console.log(password1);

    //retrieving usernames to check if it exists
    router.get('/accounts', (req, res, next)=>{
        console.log("in here");

        detail.find(function(err, accounts){
            //looping through usernames
            for (var i=0; i<accounts.length; i++){
                if (accounts[i].user_id === user_id){
                    res.json({msg: 'Username taken'});
                }
                else if(i == (accounts.length-1)){
                    if (password0 === password1){
                        let newAccount = new account({
                            user_id: this.user_id,
                            password: this.password0
                        });

                        newAccount.save((err, account)=>{
                            if(err){
                                res.json({msg: 'failed to create account'});
                            }
                            else{
                                res.json({msg: 'Account created successfully'});
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else if (password0 !== password1){
                        res.json({msg: 'Password mismatch'});
                    }
                }
            }
            //res.json(accounts);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the context for which you need to define a GET route when a POST is executed? It’s really not clear what you’re trying to accomplish here.

Comment: when i call the api from .../new, I checked and the console.log("in here"); just below router.get is never executed. I need to get the data (user_ids) from the database, to compare with the one received from a user to check if it already exists, if it does not the the user can proceed to create(POST) an account successfully. All this should happen when the (POST) .../new is executed

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you have a misunderstanding about what router.get is doing. It sounds like you want to accept a POST request from the user, then **make** a get request to check if the data already exists, and if not, then update your database.

If this is the case, the inner GET should actually use something like axios to make a request. You can make an axios request like this:

```
const axios = require('axios');

// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

If you are actually trying to accept a second request from the user after the POST, then you should **NOT** do that. Users should only make one request for one action. You'll run into all kinds of issues down that path.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can still retrieve data with only .POST, without having .GET. Removing the line having router.get, fixed the problem.

```js
router.get('/accounts', (req, res, next)=>{
```